# Unable to get Kubernetes load balancer running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

New to kubernetes and been reading on setting up an own cluster and trying to expose a service to the outside with load balancer, but I get lost in all the bits and pieces of documentation I've been reading.

Setup:
ESXi host, 4 VMs. Master = 192.168.0.30, Nodes1-3 192.168.0.31-33.
All the VMs have two nics. 2nd nic is in VLAN 6 with 192.168.6.30 for the master and 31-33 for the nodes. All IP addresses are pingable from my workstation. VMs are fedorecore.
Cluster is running with cluster-ip 10.96.0.1

helloworld.yml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

hello-world-serv.yml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-service 
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

When I apply both yml files, the 'hello-world-service' hangs forever waiting for an external-ip:

```
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/hello-world-service   LoadBalancer   10.97.220.48   <pending>     8080:31702/TCP   24s
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          2d3h
```

When I add the following:

```yaml
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.6.31
    - 192.168.6.32
    - 192.168.6.33
```

to the service, the external IPs are shown, but I still can't access the webinterface at 8080 or 31702:

```
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                              PORT(S)          AGE
service/hello-world-service   LoadBalancer   10.97.220.48   192.168.6.31,192.168.6.32,192.168.6.33   8080:31702/TCP   2m29s
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>                                   443/TCP          2d3h
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Ate you having any loadbalancer installed on your cluster like metallb?

Comment: No. I thought the service with type loadbalancer would do that? I read about ingress and ngnix, but when trying to follow these steps there was no mention of it. ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/ ) So I thought this was just another way. Do I need to install Nginx and then how do I connect my initial config above to nginx?

Comment: Have you checked this document on [create an external load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)?

Comment: I think either the cloud provider provides the load balancer capabilities, or you need to have your own load balancer configured. A very common one is `metallb`

Comment: @FariyaRahmat Yes and I thought I had done that with my hello-world-serv.yml.

Comment: @P.... looking at metallb one of the first requirements is a "cluster network configuration", so another add-on?

Comment: try following official guide , should be straight forward https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/